# How to recover missing serverauth so user can startx?

Tags: x11, xorg, login, startup

I've been using PCLinuxOS. All was OK until the Hard Drive had a bad block. After some `fsck` repair, from the shell, I tried to `startx`:

```
xauth: file /home/joe/.serverauth.2052 does not exist.
authentication failed - cannot start X server.
```

I noticed root has a `.serverauth` cookie and can `startx` it ok, but I don't know how to fix `X` access for the user.
The 80gb HD is failing so I've decided to stop try to login, only accessing it from a live cd. Case closed.

Comment: Maybe /home/joe is no longer owned by or writable by joe. What is the output of `ls -ld /home/joe` ?

Comment: @mark-plotnick drwxr-xr-x 119 joe joe 4096 May 20 19:09 /home/joe

Comment: OK, problem is somewhere else.  Will look at my copy of pclinuxos later.

Comment: Maybe `/usr/bin/Xwrapper` lost its setuid permission. It should be `rwsr-xr-x`. If that's not it, please post any error messages you see on the console or in `/home/joe/.xsession-errors`. It would also be interesting if you could create a brand new user and see whether X starts for it.

Comment: Thx Mark, I don't have a  '/usr/bin/Xwrapper' and '/home/joe/.xsession-errors' is empty.

Comment: It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information these are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116100/joe and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117261/joe.  You’ll then be able to [edit] and comment on this question.

Comment: OK, either you have an old distro that doesn't have Xwrapper, or it's missing. If you run, as root, `rpm -V -f /usr/bin/X`, are there any errors?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. To fix this, I realized I wasn't using groupinstall correctly. I did a `sudo yum grouplist` in order to identify the KDE graphical package I needed. Then I did `sudo yum groupinstall KDE Desktop` and the GUI started properly.

Comment: I accidentally deleted `libatomic` on Centos 9 using `dnf` and it broke the GUI. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo yum install gnome-shell` may also do the trick if the issue is only with serverauth.