KDE Plasma 6 doesn't start after login on Fedora 40
After upgrading to Fedora KDE 40 using dnf, KDE Plasma stopped working on my main user. It does work on a brand new user, so I assume it is something with the user configuration. I'm using a Radeon card, so it's not an Nvidia issue that I've seen mentioned online.
This is the output of kstart plasmashell:
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-mikwee'
Couldn't start kglobalaccel from org.kde.kglobalaccel.service: QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown", "The name org.kde.kglobalaccel was not provided by any .service files")
KPackageStructure of KPluginMetaData(pluginId:"org.zayronxio.vector.clock", fileName: "/home/mikwee/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.zayronxio.vector.clock/metadata.json") does not match requested format "Plasma/Applet"
KPackageStructure of KPluginMetaData(pluginId:"zayron.chaac.weather", fileName: "/home/mikwee/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/zayron.chaac.weather/metadata.json") does not match requested format "Plasma/Applet"
KPackageStructure of KPluginMetaData(pluginId:"weather.bicolor.widget", fileName: "/home/mikwee/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/weather.bicolor.widget/metadata.json") does not match requested format "Plasma/Applet"
KPackageStructure of KPluginMetaData(pluginId:"org.kde.Date.Bubble", fileName: "/home/mikwee/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.Date.Bubble/metadata.json") does not match requested format "Plasma/Applet"
kde.plasmashell: Aborting shell load: The activity manager daemon (kactivitymanagerd) is not running.
kde.plasmashell: If this Plasma has been installed into a custom prefix, verify that its D-Bus services dir is known to the system for the daemon to be activatable.
kde.plasmashell: Aborting shell load: The activity manager daemon (kactivitymanagerd) is not running.
kde.plasmashell: If this Plasma has been installed into a custom prefix, verify that its D-Bus services dir is known to the system for the daemon to be activatable.
kf.kirigami.platform: Failed to find a Kirigami platform plugin for style "Fusion"
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
kf.plasma.quick: error when loading applet "org.kde.plasma.folder" QList("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/main.qml:328:39: Type ContainmentLayoutManager.BasicAppletContainer unavailable", "file:///usr/lib64/qt6/qml/org/kde/plasma/private/containmentlayoutmanager/BasicAppletContainer.qml:263:29: Type PlasmaComponents.BusyIndicator unavailable", "file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/org/kde/plasma/components.3/BusyIndicator.qml:11:1: module \"org.kde.plasma.core\" version 2.1 is not installed")
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
Containment graphic object not valid
org.kde.plasma.libtaskmanager: Failed to determine whether virtual desktop navigation wrapping is enabled:  "The name org.kde.KWin was not provided by any .service files"
kf.plasma.quick: "file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/applet/AppletError.qml" 
 "Error loading QML file.\n160: Type PC3.Button unavailable\n45: Type Private.ButtonContent unavailable\n61: PlasmaCore.Svg is not a type\n"
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
kf.plasma.quick: error when loading applet "org.kde.panel" QList("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/ui/main.qml:323:34: Type PC3.BusyIndicator unavailable", "file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/org/kde/plasma/components.3/BusyIndicator.qml:11:1: module \"org.kde.plasma.core\" version 2.1 is not installed")
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
Containment graphic object not valid
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
kf.plasma.quick: error when loading applet "org.kde.panel" QList("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/ui/main.qml:323:34: Type PC3.BusyIndicator unavailable", "file:///usr/lib64/qt5/qml/org/kde/plasma/components.3/BusyIndicator.qml:11:1: module \"org.kde.plasma.core\" version 2.1 is not installed")
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
Containment graphic object not valid
kf.plasma.quick: "file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/applet/AppletError.qml" 
 "Error loading QML file.\n160: Type PC3.Button unavailable\n45: Type Private.ButtonContent unavailable\n61: PlasmaCore.Svg is not a type\n"
kf.plasma.quick: "file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/applet/AppletError.qml" 
 "Error loading QML file.\n160: Type PC3.Button unavailable\n45: Type Private.ButtonContent unavailable\n61: PlasmaCore.Svg is not a type\n"


How can I troubleshoot this?

have you tried the x11 version to see if that works?

startx results in this: xauth: file /home/mikwee/.serverauth.12967 does not exist

what does ``` mean?

Sorry, not used to writing comments.

does this work? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204544/how-to-recover-missing-serverauth-so-user-can-startx

Just tried installing the KDE (K Desktop Environment) group using dnf. It's already installed, and the error persists.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Happened to me today upon upgrade from Fedora 39 to Fedora 40. Fixed by removing unused packages with
sudo dnf autoremove

Not sure which package was the culprit, could be an old version of Kirigami (kf5-kirigami-1.1.0-22.fc40.x86_64) from KF5 / Plasma 5.
